# What is $D_i$ in "Common Principal Components Analysis"?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, principal-component-analysis

The following is from Ethem Alpaydin, "Introduction to Machine Learning", Fourth Edition, MIT Press, 2020, page 129.

[image]

Here, $C$ is the orthogonal matrix found from the sample covariance of all matrices (S).
But I did not understand what $D_i$ is and why we should have the above relation.

Moreover, why does it allow pooling data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D_{i}$ merely refers to the diagonal matrix that captures the variance for each principal component specific to class $i$.

We can pool data because the $C$ matrix is the same for every class, meaning principal components are derived from the collective data of all classes.